# Visual Studio .Net Solution Explorer icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I have at least two `.cshtml` files. However, in this example, code completion does not work fully on the `Complete.cshtml` page, and yet it works perfectly on the `register.cshtml` file. I notice that the visual studio icons that are provided are different. Whats the distinciton between the two icons, and why does visual studio behave differently in them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the Complete.cshtml file excluded for a reason? Have you tried to include the Complete.cshtml file in your project first? (Right click, choose Include in Project)

Comment: They were added as new items. Should they not be natively included into the project?

Comment: @mcgowan.b How did you add them?

Comment: Did you add the item via the file system (copy from another location)? If so, then they won't be included automatically. If you added them via the VS context menu (Right Click > Add > New Item), then they should be included by default.

Comment: right click on project --> add --> new item, and add a new razor v3.chstml page

Comment: Does this happen on every file you add in this project? All projects?